# On Demand Resource AppStore Upload Failure in iOS application - Disallowed Paths

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, on-demand-resources

I have an **application using ARKit**. Till the current build, all assets were included in the app bundle itself and there seem to be no issue for users in using the application.

However, I wanted to enable **On-Demand Resource** on the app so that newer modules (games)'s resources could be downloadable from AppStore, thus obviating heavy app size. Following the iOS documentations, I was able to use ODR and the application was working all right on my device. It was loading resources using ODR as it should.

When uploading to AppStore for App Review, however, I encountered the error:

[image]

My folder structure for the specific SCNAssets folder (which is tagged) is below:

[image]

Please note that the app works perfectly using ODR on my device. I have done the following and tried multiple times, but to no avail.

1. Creating a clean build.
2. Changing the Version/ Build.
3. Making sure ODR is enabled in Build Settings, etc. - all hygienic steps.And it's
   all XCode, there is no platform which I am using (such as Xamarin,
   etc.)
4. Using existing SO related solutions.

There is not much documentation by Apple on issues related to AppStore upload for ODR enabled applications. I am wondering whether within the tagged resource folder, we can have other folders as well or not, as my folder structure is right now - not sure whether this can be the reason, since the error attached points to all the folders within my folder structure.

**Help would be much appreciated.** For now, I remove my reliance on ODR and built w/o it, however this cannot be sustained for long. 
Note: The assets are all scn files, scn particle systems and images.

Code to access ODR is below (with brevity), however it the code works with my device it should work elsewhere. I think the issue might be related to folder arrangement.

**ODR Manager:**

```
class ODRManager {

    static let shared = ODRManager()
    var currentRequest: NSBundleResourceRequest?
    var currentProgressFractionCompleted: Double?

    func requestSceneWith(tag: String, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void, onFailure: @escaping (NSError) -> Void) {

        currentRequest = NSBundleResourceRequest(tags: [tag])

        guard let request = currentRequest else { return }

        request.beginAccessingResources { (error: Error?) in
            if let error = error {
                onFailure(error as NSError)
                return
            }
            onSuccess()
        }
    }
}
```

**Accessing ODR within ViewController**

```
// tagName is the name of the tag on the ODR related scnassets folder.

ODRManager.shared.requestSceneWith(tag: tagName, onSuccess: {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.game = self.gameFactory.createGame(...)
}, onFailure: { (error) in
    self.threeSurfaceLabel.text = "Problem with downloading content. Make sure internet connection is working, and restart."
})
```

Comment: Please go to edit scheme and make Build configuration from debug to release and then check

Comment: Interestingly, rather very interestingly this works. Would you kindly care to explain, why?

Comment: Absolutely! Care to explain please :)?

Comment: Its a hack, but definitely let me search the reason behind this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme

Please go to edit scheme and make Build configuration from debug to release and then check. Please don't forgot to Clean using "command + option + shift + k" before creating archive.

It will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

After a close look at the error message, you can see that the error is only referencing .DS_Store files.

.DS_Store files are hidden files created by the finder to store presentation settings for each folder.

The solution is to delete all .DS_Store files in your project subdirectories before building.

1. Close Xcode
2. Open a terminal and cd to your project directory
3. Type find . -name '.DS_Store' -type f delete
4. Open Xcode, load your project, clean, rebuild, archive and upload to the AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar failure and for me the cause was a hidden file within the ODR bundle. Removing the file fixed the problem.